# Alternatives to binding model for controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Right now my POST actions for Create and Edit have rather long function definitions because there are a lot of variables and my bind attribute contains all of them.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ProjectName,ProjectDescription,DateReceived,EffectiveDate,ExpirationDate,GeneralContractor,ProjectTerm,ProjectType,SubmissionNumber,PolicyNumber,Status,Underwriter,Division,BrokerCity,TAName,Branch,FirstNamedInsuredAddress,FirstNamedInsured,ProjectAddress")] Project project) {
```

and

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ProjectID,ProjectName,ProjectDescription,DateReceived,EffectiveDate,ExpirationDate,GeneralContractor,ProjectTerm,ProjectType,SubmissionNumber,PolicyNumber,Status,Underwriter,Division,BrokerCity,TAName,Branch,FirstNamedInsuredAddress,FirstNamedInsured,ProjectAddress")] Project project) {
```

Is there an alternative to this that would make the definitions shorter?

Here is my model:

```
public class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        FirstNamedInsuredAddress = new Address();
        ProjectAddress = new Address();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1000)]
    [Display(Name = "Project Description")]
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Received")]
    public string DateReceived { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Effective Date")]
    public string EffectiveDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Expiration Date")]
    public string ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    [Display(Name = "General Contractor")]
    public string GeneralContractor { get; set; }

    [StringLength(25)]
    [Display(Name = "Project Term")]
    public string ProjectTerm { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project Type")]
    public string ProjectType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Submission Number")]
    public long SubmissionNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    [Display(Name = "Policy Number")]
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Underwriter { get; set; }

    public string Division { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Broker/City")]
    public string BrokerCity { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name="TA Name")]
    public string TAName { get; set; }

    public string Branch { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="First Named Insured Address")]
    public Address FirstNamedInsuredAddress { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    [Display(Name="First Named Insured")]
    public string FirstNamedInsured { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Project Address")]
    public Address ProjectAddress { get; set; }

    public class Address
    {
        [StringLength(150)]
        [Display(Name="Line 1")]
        public string Line1 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(150)]
        [Display(Name="Line 2")]
        public string Line2 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string City { get; set; }

        public string State { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Zip Code")]
        public int? ZipCode { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string County { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, either I am drunk or you can just do `public ActionResult Edit(Project project)` and let it bind everything by default.

Comment: @PTwr exactly, isn't that the whole point of using Models?

Comment: @jamiedanq I think what we have here is a case of `DbModel` used as `ViewModel` with `Bind` used as workaround for lack of proper `ViewModel`, my drunk eye spots `[Key]` on id. I'll leave writing answer to someone sober :)

Comment: @PTwr yes i also see it now

Comment: @jamiedanq I removed the bind attribute and now when the POST Create method executes now I get an error that my ModelState is invalid, and the error is "The ProjectID field is required". On my create view I have `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Project.ProjectID);` which I thought would be sufficient but apparently not.

Comment: @B.Fitzgerald Do not use `DbModel` as `ViewModel`. Just read some MVC/MVVM tutorial before doing your homework ;)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the Include , you can use the Exclude.  It will only exclude the properties that you do not want post. Probably, it will lesser in most of the cases or if you want, you can remove both include and exclude , and all the data will be posted .

Ex:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "GeneralContractor")] Project project)
{

}
```

More/Useful Information:http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/2013/05/part-21-including-and-excluding.html